# Splice function on an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I'm doing a react/javascript exercice and i'm having some trouble understanding the use of `splice()` in it. 
I have 8 cards, and i need to randomly assign 4 cards to 2 players. Now everything works fine, but i don't understand the `[0]` at the end of the `let randPokemon = hand2.splice(randIndex, 1)[0];` line.

Here is the full code :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Pokedex from "./Pokedex";

class Pokegame extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    pokemon: [
      { id: 4, name: "Charmander", type: "fire", experience: 62 },
      { id: 7, name: "Squirtle", type: "water", experience: 63 },
      { id: 11, name: "Metapod", type: "bug", experience: 72 },
      { id: 12, name: "Butterfree", type: "flying", experience: 178 },
      { id: 25, name: "Pikachu", type: "electric", experience: 112 },
      { id: 39, name: "Jigglypuff", type: "normal", experience: 95 },
      { id: 94, name: "Gengar", type: "poison", experience: 225 },
      { id: 133, name: "Eevee", type: "normal", experience: 65 }
    ]
  };

  render() {
    let hand1 = [];
    let hand2 = [...this.props.pokemon];

    while (hand1.length < hand2.length) {
      let randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * hand2.length);
      let randPokemon = hand2.splice(randIndex, 1)[0];
      hand1.push(randPokemon);
    }

    console.log(hand1);
    console.log(hand2);

    return (
      <div className="Pokegame">
        <h1>Pokegame!</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Pokegame;
```

I understand (correct me if i'm wrong) that the `splice()` function can take 2 or more arguments : the first one is the index telling what position to add/remove items, the second one is the number of items to add/remove, and the next arguments being the items we want to add (but i don't use it here since i only want to remove the selected item and add it to the first hand).

Now in this case, i'm having trouble to understand how that `[0]` works or why it's here...

Comment: It's because splice returns an array and you want the first item. That is why the [0].

Comment: @JackBashford Can I ask you the reason to edit the tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) the return value of the `splice()` is array consisting of removed elements from array.

> #### Return Value
>
> An array containing the deleted elements. If only one element is removed, an array of one element is returned. If no elements are removed, an empty array is returned

Its just a way to get the removed element of the array. `hand2.splice(randIndex, 1)` will return the removed elements from array. So in this case there is only 1 element so `[0]` will get that first element.

Answer (score 0):

The `splice`-method adds or removes items from an array. It also returns always an  array-object, so the `[0]` is to access the first element in that array created/modified by splice.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [splice reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) you'll see that it actually returns an array of items that were removed by the operation.

So in this case it would remove one pokemon from the `hand2` array at the random index and return an array with one item.

`[0]` takes that item out of the array ad places it in the `randPokemon` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Because `splice` always returns an array - the `[0]` extracts the first (and only) element. You could use destructuring to achieve the same purpose:

```
let [randPokemon] = hand2.splice(randIndex, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Array.splice() gives you the new spliced array. Even though there is only one value in the array, it’s still an array, so to access the variable, you would use [0].